# how to do prefab mode in context in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have to add a prefab in rotation, but I cannot do it because I could not understand the type of ghost it is.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vESPG.png

Comment: what do you mean by "type of ghost"?

Comment: It's just a name and function is to hide on tap of objects

Comment: what type of file it is